# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql-connector

I use mysql 5.7.42.

connector-java:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.44</version>
<!--            <version>8.0.30</version>-->
</dependency]]>
```

I have tried to use mysql8.0.33 + mysql-connector-java 8.0.+, it still exist.

Can you tell me the reason? I really need your help.

Here is the whole error:
details

```
Creating a new SqlSession
Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@45c31e4d]
01:26:46  {dataSource-1} init error
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:570)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.init(DruidDataSource.java:697)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:1060)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:1056)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:104)
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper.getUrl(PageHelper.java:284)
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper.getSqlUtil(PageHelper.java:310)
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper.initSqlUtil(PageHelper.java:266)
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper.intercept(PageHelper.java:253)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:434)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:231)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:137)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getList(Unknown Source)
    at com.yang.service.impl.GoodsTypeServiceImpl.getList(GoodsTypeServiceImpl.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getList(Unknown Source)
    at com.yang.controller.GoodsTypeController.getList(GoodsTypeController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.yang.util.filter.MyWebFilter.doFilter(MyWebFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:568)
    ... 86 more
Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@45c31e4d]
Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@45c31e4d]
Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@45c31e4d]
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
### Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppE5C.png)

When I login, it can login. It query the database.

Comment: Reference: https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_43347550/article/details/106522309

Comment: I resolved it. I create a lib dictionary. Add the package mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar from the website: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/